# Rails - Controller variables are nil in the views on Production only. Works fine locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

Trying to navigate to `domain.com/company_entites/new`. And it hits the `new` action and renders the `new` form as per our `new.html.erb` view. This works fine locally.

But on the server - the same sequence errors out!

Through debugging we see that - for `CompanyEntitiesController` - none of the actions pass the data set to the @variables. But unable to figure why?

We changed the name of the variables. We set variables with constants (and not from DB) but the variables show up `nil` in the views. Note - This happens ONLY in the production server but the same code works fine locally!

CompanyEntitesController.rb

```
class CompanyEntitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_company_entity, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def new
   @company_entity = CompanyEntity.new
   respond_with(@company_entity)
  end
end
```

Error

```
Started GET "/company_entities/new" for 1.1.1.1 at 2016-03-04 09:39:57 -0500 I, 

[2016-03-04T09:39:57.737434 #7243]  INFO -- : Processing by CompanyEntitiesController#new as HTML I,

[2016-03-04T09:39:57.826523 #7243]  INFO -- :   Rendered company_entities/_form.html.erb (5.7ms) I,

[2016-03-04T09:39:57.826932 #7243]  INFO -- :   Rendered company_entities/new.html.erb within layouts/admin_lte_2 (11.6ms) E,

[2016-03-04T09:39:57.827367 #7243] ERROR -- : Caught exception : ArgumentError : First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty E,


[2016-03-04T09:39:57.827485 #7243] ERROR -- : /home/bobdiya/apps/2dotO_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.12/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:423:in `form_for'
/home/bobdiya/apps/2dotO_staging/releases/20160304142845/app/views/company_entities/_form.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_company_entities__form_html_erb__3158067205622819281_41143500'
/home/bobdiya/apps/2dotO_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.12/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
/home/bobdiya/apps/2dotO_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
/home/bobdiya/apps/2dotO_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.12/lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
I, 

[2016-03-04T09:39:57.829225 #7243]  INFO -- :   Rendered text template (0.1ms)
I, 
[2016-03-04T09:39:57.829886 #7243]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 92ms (Views: 1.4ms)
```

**Edit**

- Debugging as suggestion by @brahmana

**new**

```
 def new
    @company_entity = CompanyEntity.new
    Rails.logger.debug @company_entity.inspect+"debugging company----------------------------------------"
 end
```

`/app/views/company_entities/new.html.erb`

```
<section class="content">
<div class="box box-primary">
 <div class="box-header">
   <h3 class="box-title">New Company Entity</h3>
 </div><!-- /.box-header -->

<%= render 'form' %>
```

`/app/views/company_entities/_form.html.erb`

```
   <div class="box-body">
  <%= debug @company_entity %>
 <%= debug "debugging in view ========================== "%>
  <%= form_for(@company_entity) do |f| %>
   <% if @company_entity.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
       <h2><%= pluralize(@company_entity.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this company_entity from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @company_entity.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :area %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :area , class: "form-control"%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :address %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :address , class: "form-control"%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :code %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :code , class: "form-control"%>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :ext %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :ext , class: "form-control"%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :type %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:type, CompanyEntity.space_types, :first, :last, {prompt: "Select a category"}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :city_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a City"}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
  </div>
 </div>  
<div class="box-footer" >
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary " %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Debug trace in log**

```
    Started GET "/company_entities/new" for 106.51.225.130 at 2016-03-07 01:41:37 -0500 I,
    [2016-03-07T01:41:37.643152 #19039]  INFO -- : Processing by CompanyEntitiesController#new as HTML I,
    [2016-03-07T01:41:37.668663 #19039]  INFO -- :   Rendered company_entities/_form.html.erb (11.4ms) I,
    [2016-03-07T01:41:37.668962 #19039]  INFO -- :   Rendered company_entities/new.html.erb within layouts/admin_lte_2 (14.7ms)E,
    [2016-03-07T01:41:37.669333 #19039] ERROR -- : Caught exception : ArgumentError : First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty E,
    [2016-03-07T01:41:37.669407 #19039] ERROR -- : /home/bobdiya/apps/2dotO_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.12/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:423:in `form_for'
/home/bobdiya/apps/2dotO_staging/releases/20160307064025/app/views/company_entities/_form.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_company_entities__form_html_erb__779177916647948870_62782300'
/home/bobdiya/apps/2dotO_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.12/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
/home/bobdiya/apps/2dotO_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
/home/bobdiya/apps/2dotO_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.12/lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'I,


    [2016-03-07T01:41:37.670276 #19039]  INFO -- :   Rendered text template (0.0ms)
I, 
   [2016-03-07T01:41:37.670584 #19039]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms (Views: 0.7ms)
I, 
   [2016-03-07T01:41:37.790672 #19036]  INFO -- : Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 106.51.225.130 at 2016-03-07 01:41:37 -0500
I, 
   [2016-03-07T01:41:37.806287 #19036]  INFO -- : Processing by ApplicationController#no_route as 
I, 
   [2016-03-07T01:41:37.806478 #19036]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"unmatched_route"=>"favicon"}
I, 
   [2016-03-07T01:41:37.817066 #19036]  INFO -- :   Rendered application/no_route.html.erb within layouts/admin_lte_2 (3.3ms)
I, 


[2016-03-07T01:41:38.947676 #19036]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_notification.html.erb (5.9ms)
I, [2016-03-07T01:41:38.949171 #19036]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_admin_lte_2_header.html.erb (11.9ms)
I, [2016-03-07T01:41:38.962706 #19036]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_admin_lte_2_sidebar.html.erb (10.3ms)
I, [2016-03-07T01:41:38.973312 #19036]  INFO -- :   Rendered popups/_add_new_contact.html.erb (7.6ms)
I, [2016-03-07T01:41:38.974101 #19036]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 1167ms (Views: 1166.7ms)
```

**Note**: I've renamed `new` to `new1` and changed the routing preference and with the same code in controller and view - it worked!

Comment: you shouldn't need that respond_with in your new action. did you run your migrations in production?

Comment: Ok. I'll remove; We are using MongoDB. Also - say for index action - I have set the variable - @company_entities to a simple string `hello` and simply printing it on view will still be `nil`

Comment: please post your view as well as that index action. also post your routes.rb in relevant part.

Comment: Need the `app/views/company_entities/new.html.erb` view and the partial `app/views/company_entities/_form.html.erb` which is where (in your app code) the exception is rooted. A few log lines in the view before the partial is rendered, printing the variables passed to the partial, would clarify things.

Comment: @brahmana I've placed debugs and shared the views.

Comment: Try next: form_for(Company Entity.new) - it's not good practice but for find out problem may helpful.

Comment: @bobdiya something is amiss here. None of the log lines are printed. May be you need to change `debug` to `info` for that. Also the stack trace mentions `app/views/company_entities/_form.html.erb:5` (line no 5). In the view that corresponds to `<% if @company_entity.errors.any? %>` which I don't think is right. Please post the exact code which is causing issues. Ultimately, how are you passing the `@company_entity` to your `_form.html.erb` partial? More info : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials